# text string must be rendered with <text> component error only on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm getting this weird error when I'm running my code on Expo Go on IOS

I'm new to react native and I don't know what to do

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ButtonBasics extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    alert("Don't touch that button!")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <text>Press the button</text>
          <Button title="Press" onPress={this._onPressButton} color="#57a9af" />
        <View/>
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#d6f0f2',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Components start with a Capital letter :) `<text>` --> `<Text>`. Also note your closing tag: the `/` shouldn't be at the end or it's self closing.

Answer (score 0):

Well There are multiple problems with your Code,

1. `<text>` is not a valid component. It is `<Text>` with Capital `T`. You have imported the right Component but using the wrong Tag.
2. You have three  end tags. While you have only two start tags.

So your code should be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ButtonBasics extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    alert("Don't touch that button!")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text>Press the button</Text>
          <Button title="Press" onPress={this._onPressButton} color="#57a9af" />
        <View/>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#d6f0f2',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```